# Не регистрируется хэндлер Python aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Не понимаю что не так, последний хэндлер не регистрируется никак. Уже перепробывал все что мог придумать. Без регистрации все работает, а так нет [image: мой код]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ найден, нужно переставить регистрацию хендлеров и функции. Поставить cancel_setup после ожидания первого состояния, тогда все работает